# I want to sort my struct by alphabetical order, but if i do the sort, my program doesn't give any output

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct kezdo
{
    int mennyi;
    char betu;
}KEZDO;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int j;
    int i;
    int db=0;
    int volt=0;
    char sajt[22];
    FILE* f=fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(f==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Hiba a fajl megnyitasaban!");
    }
    int k = 20;
    KEZDO t[k];
    KEZDO tmp;
    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        t[i].mennyi = 0;
    }
    while(fgets(sajt,22,f)!=0)
    {
        if(sajt[strlen(sajt)-1] == '\n')
        {
            sajt[strlen(sajt)-1] = '\0';
        }
        for(i=0;i<k;i++)
        {
            if(t[i].betu == toupper(sajt[0]))
            {
                t[i].mennyi++;
                volt=1;
            }
        }
        if(volt==0)
        {
                t[db].betu = toupper(sajt[0]);
                t[db].mennyi++;
                db++;
        }
        else
        {
            volt = 0;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<db;i++)
    {
        printf("%c: %d\n", t[i].betu, t[i].mennyi);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried `strcmp` and `stricmp` but neither worked. I tried to fully change the struct by sorting the struct properties. When the struct properties are sorted it doesn't work, but it worked before in a non-sorted order.  What is preventing output when the struct properties are sorted?

Comment: for starters, the `betu` field for each object in the `t` array isn't initialized, so `if(t[i].betu == toupper(sajt[0]))` invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can see in your code, you want to sort on `char betu`. One way to sort structures is via `qsort` but that'd require comparator function stated below:

```
  int compare(const void *void_a, const void *void_b)
  {
     const KEZDO *a = void_a;    
     const KEZDO *b = void_b;

     return (a->betu) < (b->betu);
  }
  //Perform sort like this;
 qsort((void *) &t, db, sizeof(KEZDO) , compare );
```

Moreover, `qsort` is in `#include <stdlib.h>`